# Read/Write Split in Mongodb

Tags: load-balancing, mongodb, multi-threading

We are looking for some load balancing tool which can split read and write load in between replica and master node, I know it can be possible through driver or application level but I would like to do at databases level i.e ProxySQL for MySQL DB

Comment: Can you elaborate on your use case and deployment topology (replica set or sharded cluster? # of replica set members or shards?). External load balancers and proxies are typically not recommended for MongoDB as they complicate the normal server discovery and monitoring process used by drivers. Discretionary use of [Read Preferences](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/) is the preferred approach for secondary reads. For some important considerations I recommend reviewing: [Can I use more replica nodes to scale?](http://www.askasya.com/post/canreplicashelpscaling/).